# Loop in R using changing variable to write and name files

Tags: r, loops, time-series, gis, netcdf

I am trying to create a loop in R that reads daily values of a netcdf file I have imported and converts them into annual sums, then creates a raster for each year. I have converted the netcdf into an array - this is named Biased_corrected.array in my code below. I am not sure how to include the variable 'year' in my file names as it changes with each iteration of the loop.  I have tried using paste but this seems to be where it fails.  Any suggestions?

```
# read in file specifying which days correspond to years
YearsDays <- read.csv("Data\\Years.csv") # a df with 49 obs. of 3 variables (year, start day, and end day

YearsDays[1,2:3]  #returns 1 and 366 (the days for year 1972)
YearsDays[2,2:3]  #returns 367 and 731 (the days for year 1973)
YearsDays[1,1] #returns 1972
YearsDays[2,1] #returns 1973

counter <- 1
startyear <- YearsDays[1,1]
year <- startyear

while(year < 2021){
  #set variables to loop through
  startday <- YearsDays[counter,2]
  endday <- YearsDays[counter,3]

  BC_rain.slice <- Biased_corrected.array[,,startday:endday]
  paste(year, "_Annual_rain") <- apply(BC_rain.slice, c(1,2), sum)
  
  #save data in a raster
  paste(year, "_rain_r") <- raster(t(paste(year, "_Annual_Rain"), xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y), crs=WGS84)
  
  
  # move on to next year
  counter <- counter + 1
  year <- 1971 + counter
}
```

EDIT:  The working code for anyone interested:

```
YearsDays <- read.csv("Data\\Years.csv") # a df with 49 obs. of 3 variables (year, start day, and end day

for (idx in seq(nrow(YearsDays))){
  
  #set variables to loop through
  year <- YearsDays[idx,1]
  startday <- YearsDays[idx,2]
  endday <- YearsDays[idx,3]

  BC_rain.slice <- Biased_corrected.array[,,startday:endday]
  assign(paste(year, "_Annual_rain"),apply(BC_rain.slice, c(1,2), sum))
  annual_rain <- apply(BC_rain.slice, c(1,2), sum)
  
  #save data in a raster
  assign(paste(year, "_rain_r"),raster(t(annual_rain), xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y), crs=WGS84))
         
}
```

Comment: `paste()` is a function, you can't assign _to_ it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `paste` to create a variable name as you've listed. You can enclose it within `assign` or `eval`, however it may be easier to instead store your results within a data frame. Below is an example of what I believe you're trying to achieve. I have also replaced your while loop and counter with a for loop iterating over years:

```
YearsDays <- read.csv("Data\\Years.csv") # a df with 49 obs. of 3 variables (year, start day, and end day

output <- data.frame(year = YearsDays[,1], rain_r = NA)

for (idx in seq(nrow(YearsDays))){
  
  #set variables to loop through
  year <- YearsDays[idx,1]
  startday <- YearsDays[idx,2]
  endday <- YearsDays[idx,3]
  
  BC_rain.slice <- Biased_corrected.array[,,startday:endday]
  annual_rain <- apply(BC_rain.slice, c(1,2), sum)
  
  #save data in a raster
  output$rain_r[output$year == year] <- raster(t(annual_rain, xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y), crs=WGS84))

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this didn't work because (I think) a raster is not a data frame.  I did use your loop though with my paste embedded in the assign function and got it do do what I needed.

Comment: Great - raster wasn't a base R function so I didn't know what library it was from in order to test.

Answer (score 0):

How about to replace your part

```
paste(year, "_Annual_rain") <- apply(BC_rain.slice, c(1,2), sum)
  
#save data in a raster
paste(year, "_rain_r") <- raster(t(paste(year, "_Annual_Rain"), xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y), crs=WGS84)
```

to

```
txt <- paste0(year, "_Annual_rain <- apply(BC_rain.slice, c(1,2), sum)")
eval(parse(text = txt))

# save data in a raster
txt <- paste0(year, "_rain_r <- raster(t(", year, "_Annual_Rain), xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y), crs=WGS84)")
eval(parse(text = txt))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried this and got error messages, I think because there is a mistake in where you have your double quotations??